# Javascript shuffle letters

Tags: javascript

I found how to shuffle letters in tutorialzine. The URL is http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/

I tried to change the settings so that I can change the text being shuffled with predefined words. For example when page loads shuffle the content of the id container1. When this finishes wait for 4 seconds and then shuffle the content of the id container2. When this finishes wait 4 seconds etc. This is the script.js code:

```
$(function(){
    var container = $("#container1")
    container.shuffleLetters();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(function() {
            var container = $("#container2")
            container.shuffleLetters();
            setTimeout(function() { }, 4000);
    });
    },4000);
});
```

At the end I want to start again from the beginning. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `$(function() { ...})` is jQuery's "document ready"; doing it inside the first `setTimeout` is nonsensical--just pass in the function. Not saying it's the only issue, but it's an issue.

Comment: If the answer given was acceptable, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo that will work for any number of containers:

```
$(function(){
  function shuff () {
    if (counter == $obj.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    $obj.eq(counter).shuffleLetters();
    counter++;
    setTimeout(shuff, 4000);
  }

  var counter = 0, $obj = $('#container1, #container2');

  // safety check to make sure there is at least one container
  if ($obj[0]) {
    shuff();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys very much. @Jack this is exactly what I wanted but now I am curious  about something else. Is there a way to have a steady string like "This is" and the javascript to rotate a set of predefined words like "my home", "my car", "my neighbor". Those predefined words should use the shuffle script you shared. Again thanks a lot.